# Conditional line spacing in ERb partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping, erb

This is the code for an address partial I just wrote. People might put single line addresses in either street line, company name is optional, etc... It works exactly how I want it to, but I know that checking each variable twice is ugly and terrible.

```
 <%= "#{a.name}" unless a.name.blank? %>
 <% unless a.name.blank? %> <br> <% end %>

 <%= "#{a.company_name}" unless a.company_name.blank? %>
 <% unless a.company_name.blank? %> <br> <% end %>

 <%= "#{a.street_1}" unless a.street_1.blank? %>
 <% unless a.street_1.blank? %> <br> <% end %>

 <%= "#{a.street_2}" unless a.street_2.blank? %>
 <% unless a.street_2.blank? %> <br> <% end %>

 <%= "#{a.city}, #{a.state} &nbsp; #{a.zip}" %>
```

So, my gratuitous use of unless aside, how should I be putting in a conditional line break?

**Update:**

As discussed below, it is dangerous to use .html_safe on user input. If you do use a helper method as suggested below, you must also sanitize all user input on the way into the database. I've rewritten the code above as:

```
<% unless a.name.blank? %>
  <%= a.name %>
  <br>
<% end %>

<% unless a.company_name.blank? %>
  <%= a.company_name %>
  <br>    
<% end %>        

<% unless a.street_1.blank? %>
  <%= a.street_1 %>
  <br>               
<% end %>

<% unless a.street_2.blank? %>
  <%= a.street_2 %> 
  <br>               
<% end %>

<%= "#{a.city}, #{a.state}" %> &nbsp; <%= a.zip %>
```

The redundant checking was just me overcomplicating things. I'd strongly recommend against using .html_safe in a situation like this, since you create new problems for yourself: sanitizing the input, and remembering which fields are safe. Better to not override the sensible protection Rails provides.

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many ways to go about cleaning it up, but a helper would be appropriate here:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def format_address(a)
    top = [a.name, a.company_name, a.street_1, a.street_2]
    top.reject! {|s| s.blank?} # remove null and empty values

    "#{top.join('<br/>')}#{a.city}, #{a.state} &nbsp; #{a.zip}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= format_address(a) %>
```

Comment: Doesn't this still suffer from either escaping or XSS issues? Maybe you could join with newline and use simple format...

Comment: Only if the values are coming from user input. I would clean any values of HTML before saving them to the database in the first place.

Comment: OP indicated that it is coming from user input. This method should not be used without additional sanitization, to be sure.